# How to set environment variables separated by dots

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, tomcat7

I have to set an environment variable separated by dot in my tomcat startup script.
For example

```
host.name=localhost
```

I know shell doesn't accept dot separated variables.
Is there a work around ?

I found somewhere that we can use env variable but that doesnt seem to work. I used

```
env host.name=localhost
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for your reply AB. However i found a much better solution.
I simply added in the `CATALINA_OPTS` variable of tomcat in the file `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh`:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dhost.name=localhost"
```

This worked exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why that is required for Tomcat. All configuratios are in eg: `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`. I have worked for several years with Tomcat, but this kind of configuration I've never needed. Anyway [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93533/107084) is your answer.

TL;DR

```
env "host.name=localhost"
```

Test with:

```
env "host.name=localhost" perl -le 'print $ENV{"host.name"}'
```

*or with Java:*

Create a runnable `jar`

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Map;

public class PrintEnv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(envName + ": " + env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

and test with:

```
env "host.name=localhost" java -jar PrintEnv.jar | grep host.name
```